# django-admin.py startproject не работает

Tags: python, django

В этой же дериктории я уже создал два проекта, всё работало. Нужно создать ещё, и теперь проект не создаётся, после нажатия enter открывается файл django-admin.py

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте не указывать расширение файла:

```
django-admin startproject project
```

Или запустить файл, явно используя интерпретатор `Python`:

```
python django-admin.py startproject project
```